# Экземпляр обобщенного класса

Tags: java, generics, компилятор

Компилятор вообще не создает экземпляры обобщенного класса или компилятор не создает более одного экземпляра обобщенного класса?

**upd**

[Читаю](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) (стр 399)

> Прежде чем продолжить дальше, следует сказать, что **компилятор Java на самом
>   деле не создает разные версии класса Gen или любого другого обобщенного
>   класса**. Теоретически это было бы удобно, но на практике дело обстоит иначе.
>   Вместо этого компилятор удаляет все сведения об обобщенных типах, выполняя
>   необходимые операции приведения типов, чтобы сделать поведение прикладного
>   кода таким, как будто создана конкретная версия класса Gen. Таким образом, **имеется
>   только одна версия класса Gen , которая существует в прикладной программе**.
>   Процесс удаления обобщенной информации об обобщенных типах называется
>   стиранием, и мы еще вернемся к этой теме далее в главе.

Приводить версию класса Gen думаю не нужно, потому как речь идет об обобщенном классе как таковом.

У меня сложилось понимание, что компилятору, имеющему дело с обобщенным классом, нет необходимости создавать его экземпляры, и он использует тем самым одну версию класса. Верно ли я понимаю?

Comment: Создает сколько угодно экземпляров.

Comment: экземпляром класса обычно называют объект. но вы вероятно спрашиваете про что-то другое. можете уточнить вопрос? добавьте пример кода.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman: обновил

Comment: type erasure же, просто в рантайме на самом деле будет существовать единственный Generic<Object> с кастами в нужных местах